# How to make app UI to work 100% same on all devices?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-screen-support

How to make sure that my App's popup or text appears exactly how I intended it to appear in all screen sizes? I want the aspect ratio of the popup to appear same and all the text that appears at the time of designing the popup to be same in all the devices.

Imagine an image who's size and content will be same across devices. But for some reason I can not use image here, the requirement is to use popup with text and butto. I dont want any screen to cut the popup or make the text of the popup disappear or turn to crap.

I can not do testing with one device at a time as I read on a site that there are over 10,000 android devices :|

Is there anyway or any tool part of Android Studio which can like quickly draw outlines of all the phones screen sizes to help me understand what aspect ratio is right for my popup?

Im a noob so my question may not make sense to you so please bear with me.

Comment: In the design view of a layout you can pick a device at the top. In the "other" section there are some really small devices you can try out.

Comment: That is testing with one device at a time and I read on a site that there are over 10,000 android devices :|

Comment: That's true, but you won't be able to handle them all individually. You have to look at the extremes. This page might be of use to you https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's going to be nearly impossible to get things to appear 100% the same across all devices and browsers – Android runs on all sorts of devices and there are probably hundreds or thousands of different possible screen sizes, in addition to browser and operating system quirks.  Start with identifying specific devices and screen sizes you wish to support. See Android's [screen compatibility overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support) for some good information on this topic.

If possible look at user analytics to narrow down the most common devices, operating system versions, and browsers, then test against those.

Comment: Okay so can I at least have a popup which will show full popup box and all the text and buttons even if every alphabet doesnt appear exactly where  I intended it to be? Is it possible to show everything in the popup without it being cut or omitted in any way whatsoever?

Comment: This depends a little bit on the layout you're trying to achieve and the screen sizes you choose to support - but the short answer is yes. You should be able to get all of your content on the screen without being cut off.